# Add Column of a table on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table created when page loads

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="col2">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td class="col2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td class="col2">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now how do I add all value of `col2` column and show it on alert ??

In this case I should get `6` on the alert box as result

Comment: Will it always be integer values?

Comment: integer or double always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var total = 0;
$("table .col2").each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).html(), 10);
});
alert(total);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pTn2V/

**Edit**:
You can also use `parseFloat()` if you have doubles in there.

Comment: based on the OP's comment you can change your method to `parseFloat()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
         $(document).ready(
             function() {
                 total = 0;
                 $('.col2').each(function(){
                     total+=parseInt($(this).text());

                 });
                 alert(total); 
             }    

          );

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be like the following:

Your html:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>name</th><th>value</th></tr>
    <tr><td>A</td><td id="val1">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td><td id="val2">2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td><td id="val3">3</td></tr>
</table>
```

then Your Javascript, after the HTML code like the following:

```
 <script>

var sum = 
    parseFloat(parseInt(document.getElementById('val1').innerText) 
             + parseInt(document.getElementById('val2').innerText) 
             + parseInt(document.getElementById('val3').innerText));
   alert(sum);
 </script>
```